# Elasticsearch query on string representation of number

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I have an indexed field called `amount`, which is of string type. The value of `amount` can be either *one* or *1*. Say in this example, we have `amount=1` as an indexed document but, I try to search for *one*, ElasticSearch will not return the value unless I put *1* for the search query. Thoughts on how I can get this to work? I'm thinking a tokenizer is what's needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't want this for sevenmillionfourhundredfifteenthousendtwohundredfourteen and the like, but only for a small number of values.

At index time I would convert everything to a proper number and store it in a numerical field, which then even allows to sort --- if you need it. Apart from this I would use synonyms at index and at query time and map everything to the digit-strings, but in a general text field that is searched by default.